# ScaleY animation in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, storyboard

Why below code doesn't change `ScaleY` to `1`?

```
  var transform = new ScaleTransform { ScaleY = 0 };
  var story = new Storyboard();
  var animation = new DoubleAnimation { 
                    Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0)), To = 1 };
  Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, transform);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("ScaleY"));
  story.Children.Add(animation);
  story.Begin();
```

I use `transform` indirectly: it use for render some `UIElements` and kept in their `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Are you actually *using* `transform` anywhere? E.g., assigning it to an element's `RenderTransform`?

Comment: @JoeWhite, look to my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it perhaps work if you drop the Storyboard and just call [BeginAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590761.aspx) directly?

```
var transform = new ScaleTransform { ScaleY = 0 };
var animation = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.Zero, To = 1 };

transform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScalyYProperty, animation);
```

Note that this will only have any effect if the animation's [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) has a value of `HoldEnd`. Otherwise the animated property will immediately revert back to its local value (which is 0 here). Fortunately `HoldEnd` is the default value for `FillBehavior`.

And of course the `transform` should be *used* somewhere.